# how to avoid bot detection on websites using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, bots, detection, rpa

We are trying to automate process using selenium python for a website but as we proceed with the process the bot gets detected every time and a captcha comes up. Even though a human solve that captcha the website does not allow to move forward and continuously keeps detecting the bot and again and again shows the captcha to solve. So far we have tried all methods whichever we have explored to overcome it but none of method worked. Can someone help on this issue ?

**Some of the methods tried:**

1.) using spoofing user agents

2.) using proxies

3.) turn-off useAutomationExtension

4.) changing the property value of navigator for web driver to undefined

5.) disable-blink-features

6.) exclude the collection of enable-automation switches

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something called "Undetected ChromeDriver" you can check out!

Optimized Selenium Chromedriver patch which does not trigger anti-bot services like Distill Network / Imperva / DataDome / Botprotect.io Automatically downloads the driver binary and patches it.

[here is the link](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver)

Here is another useful website you can check out, this website shows if a site will detect you using selenium or not or anything like that:

[LINK](https://nowsecure.nl)

Also for future reference on Stack Overflow you should steer away from opinion-based questions. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more about asking a good question.

Comment: Actually we had problem of captcha on two sites , by this solution we are able to solve for one website, but the other website is still detecting the bot and showing a captcha. Can you please suggest some more solutions that we can try out ?

Comment: I'm also have same poroblem that DataDome detect my selenium even if I used the undetected-chromedriver they also know that is bot and blocked my IP address for 24 hours.. they display recapcha but even if I solved it they blocked my IP ... any hints here ?